# How to permanently change proofing language in OneNote v. 16.70?

Tags: language, microsoft-onenote, proofing

My proofing language is set to Norwegian, however, I would like to permanently change it to English (United Kingdom). I am able to set it to English, but every time I make a new document, it changes back to Norwegian. Any advice? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I typed in English on a Spanish keyboard. Yes, OneNote (and other 365 software) sets the proofing language based on your keyboard.

The solution for me was to go to:

1. Windows Settings > Time & Language > Language & Region
2. Under "Language" select "Add a language" then "English UK"
3. Select the 3 dot menu and "Language options"
4. Under "Keyboard" select "Add a keyboard" then "Norwegian"
5. Remove the "United Kingdom" keyboard

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work for me, I've changed language everywhere but for some reason OneNote still keeps defaulting back to US English for Autocorrect.  I've tried input settings, keyboard, system language, and in the Proofing settings and it's still doing it. There must be a global setting its getting from somewhere but it really shouldn't be this difficult

Comment: If you check the system tray icon for the keyboard layout what does it say? There are 2 languages: in the 1st row (bigger font) is the language OneNote will use to autocorrect, and in the 2nd row (smaller) is that of your keyboard. It sounds like the first one is still set to US English for you and that's what you need to change.

Comment: thanks Caro, I kept playing with all the language settings, an eventually it worked and is now proofing in English UK, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

- Open OneNote menu *File > Options*
- Click on section Language
- Under "Office authoring languages and proofing" choose your language
  (if not in the list, use the button "Add a Language...")
- If you see next to it a blue link saying "Proofing available",
  click it and let it do its job
- While this language is selected, click the button
  "Set as Preferred"
- Click OK.

Note that this will apply to the whole of Office.

Comment: Note that this answer applies to the Office OneNote and not to the discontinued Microsoft Store version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can not seem to find the option button for files?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft Office installed? Is OneNote in Start menu called "OneNote" or "OneNote for Windows X"?

Comment: This does not seem to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t got Microsoft Office installed no. OneNote is called «Microsoft OneNote»

I have found one solution by changing keyboard to English keyboard while writing (meaning I would have to change keyboards when writing Norwegian) but if there is a better solution that would be ideal.

Comment: This isn't actually an answer, this is a comment. You could expand it to one by adding more context (please see the [guidelines](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)), for example describing your solution; or you could close this and instead [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1772059/edit) the question "I have this workaround...". As is this is very likely to get [deleted](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). Please take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work.